# How do I access the individual value of a database column?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to read a single column of data from an SQL Database, however it is always returning undefined for me.

I have tried searching around and have indeed attempted to use callbacks, but I think I am doing it incorrectly.

Here is the code I am using

```
if(message.toLowerCase() === "!coins")
  {
    con.connect(function(err) {
      var usernameBal = user['display-name']
      con.getUserCoins = function(usernameBal, callback){
        con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =?", [usernameBal],
        function(err, results){
          callback(undefined, results)
        })
      }

      con.getUserCoins(usernameBal, function(err, results)
    {
      console.log(results);
      console.log(results.coins);
    })
      //con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =?", [usernameBal], function (err, result) {
    });
}
```

What I would expect is for results.coins to display 37, as that is what it is set as in my SQL database. Instead it returns as undefined. However the console.log(results) does in fact return

```
[ RowDataPacket { username: 'Joshj5hawk', coins: '37' } ]
```

Any tips would be very grateful. I have a decent understanding when it comes to syntax and the like, but this is my first foray into MySQL or working with databases in general.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
results[0].coins instead of results.coins
```

Comment: You're a saint. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you have multiple arrays in future, do forEach or map instead of [key].